# AWS ebextensions crontab error: no such file (but it exists)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running an amazon web services web server tier elastic beanstalk application, and I would like to run a script every 3 hours.  I've googled around quite a bit, and the answer for this seems to be to create a ".ebextensions" folder, with a .config file that looks something like this:

```
commands:
  01_cronjobs:
    leader_only: true
    command: "cat .ebextensions/etss.txt > /etc/cron.d/crontab_etss && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/crontab_etss"
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the application fails to deploy with the error:

```
[Instance: xxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cat: .ebextensions/etss.txt: No such file or directory. command 01_cronjobs in .ebextensions/config.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I have an etss.txt file in my .ebextensions folder that looks like this:

```
0 */3 * * * /usr/bin/php download_etss_tar.php > /dev/null
#blank newline here
```

I also have tried putting it in the root and referencing it there.  Why can't the cron find the file that I know exists in the zip?  What am I doing wrong here?

Furthermore, I also tried using the full file name, to no avail:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cat: /var/www/html/.ebextensions/etss.txt: No such file or directory. command 01_cronjobs in .ebextensions/etss.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should always use complete paths to both executables and files in cron jobs, rather than assuming the job runs with the working directory set to a specific directory or that the search path will include certain paths.  The most likely explanation is that this job doesn't run in the "right" directory, so the file is indeed not found.

Comment: I agree and follow this in all my other non-AWS projects -- I've just been following online examples to get this far.  Do you happen to know what the default full path is for AWS eb projects?  I'd assume /var/www/html but I am having trouble finding this information for some reason. Edit: actually, I must have tracked it down in the past because I see a reference to /var/www/html elsewhere. I will try this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Doesn't seem like that worked. Response=> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cat: /var/www/html/.ebextensions/etss.txt: No such file or directory. command 01_cronjobs in .ebextensions/etss.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Comment: try "client_commands"